# How do I populate a JSON array with the data from my MYSQL database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

So I have a database that I can query using ExpressJS and NodeJS. The Database is a MySQL db. and the data within looks like this:

```
id: 1
username: 'someUsername'
email: 'randomEmail@email.email'
```

**I want to somehow put the data from within the database into a JSON list and then map over it and show it to the user.** Another option to achieve this, I reasoned, would be to populate the state of the app. I've thought of creating some class component, adding a mapStateToProps and assign the data returned from the queries to the state and then use the data from the state in the Reactapp itself. I am not so sure if that would be effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the return data that you get from the SQL query is itself an array of objects,
Your answer lies in simply iterating over the returned data and assigning it to whatever object you like.

```
let queryResults = returnedQueryData // data returned from SQL query
let jsonarray = {}

for (row in queryResults) {
  jsonarray[row.id] = {
    id: row['id'],
    username: row['username'],
    email: row['email']
  }
```

To access data from the JSON array use

```
Object.keys(jsonarray).forEach(e => {
    // Here e is the object element from the JSON array
}
```

Comment: is jsonarray not being overwritten each time in the loop?

Answer (score 3):

This is the minimum code example for a component that fetches data from your backend onLoad, and displaying the data using .map, without using redux (mapstatetoprops)

```
const DisplayData = () => {

     const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);

     
     const fetchData = async () => {
         const results = await fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
         setData(data)
     }

     useEffect(() => {
         fetchData()
     },[])
 return ( <div>
           { data.map(item => <p>{item.name}</p> }
           <pre>
             { JSON.stringify(null, data, 4) }
          </pre>
         </div>
}
```